# Determine whether each of these combinations of R 1 and R 2 must be an equivalence relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I have this question but not really sure how to do it when there is union and intersection symbol. I easily get confused when these two symbols appear. From my understanding I know that equivalence relation is a relation which is reflective, symmetric and transitive. Can anyone guide me. Thanks!

Suppose that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are equivalence relations on the set $S$. Determine whether each of these combinations of $R_1$ and $R_2$ must be an equivalence relation.

a) $R_1 \cup R_2$

b) $R_1 \cap R_2$

Answer (score 1):

For union, transitivity fails.

For instance $aR_1 b$, $bR_2 c$ does not imply either of $aR_1 c$ or $aR_2 c$.

Intersection is true, denote $R_1\cap R_2$ by $\sim$.

Reflexive: $aR_1a$, $a R_2 a$, so $a\sim a$.

Symmetric: Given $a \sim b$, $a R_1 b$ and $a R_2 b$.

Thus $bR_1a$ and $bR_2a$, i.e. $b\sim a$.

Similarly for transivity, one can show that $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ implies $a\sim c$.

Comment: So when I encounter this type of question, I should write down some variable and try to see if it can fulfill the relations? For the interception, may I have more details? I am not very sure how to show it. Thanks!

Comment: I wrote some details on intersection. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

A nice answer is already provided by @yoyostein but this question invites a significant generalisation, which is relevant in so many areas, which I thought should be included since you are sometimes confused by union/intersections. The more general statement is, loosely

> Intersection preserves "forall" type statements, whereas Union preserves "There exists" type statements.

We can make this precise,

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, and $\phi(x,y)$ is some predicate (you can think of this as a "statement" that takes the variables $x,y$) then if we know

$$\forall_{x,y\in A}[\phi(x,y)] \land \forall_{x,y \in B}[\phi(x,y)] $$

We can conclude

$$\forall_{x,y\in A\cap B}[\phi(x,y)]$$

The same is not true in general for the Union.

If on the other hand we know that

$$\forall_{x\in A}\exists_{y\in A}[\phi(x,y)] \land\forall_{x\in B}\exists_{y\in B}[\phi(x,y) ]$$

Then we can conclude

$$\forall_{x\in A\cup B}\exists_{y\in A\cup B}[\phi(x,y)] $$

But we cannot conclude the same for the intersection.

This may seem like a bit of an arbitrary exercise, but so many statements you encounter have this form:

1. Transitivity had a $\forall_x\forall_y\forall_z$ form, hence it was preserved by intersection, but not by unions in general.
2. The property of being a subgroup of a group has the form $\forall_x\forall_y$, hence the intersection of subgroups is a subgroup.
3. The property of a function being surjective has the form $\forall_x\exists_y$, hence the union of two surjective functions (with disjoint domains) is a surjective function.
4. The property of a function being injective has the form $\forall_x\forall_y$, hence the intersection of injective functions is an injective function!

Using this gimmick, you can actually get a feel for what intersection and union does to objects, oftentimes all you need to know about a property of an object to answer these kinds of questions is which of the two types of statements defines it. You should still prove that the property is preserved, but the proof is essentially the same each time